# JPA EntityManager Construction

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I am trying to learn how to create an entity manager using best practices. I am creating a JavaSE application using maven split into separate projects so that I can use different projects to create applications with different capabilities.

So far I have created my entities and tested them using `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Now I have created my `persistence.xml` and I am trying to understand how to connect my `EntityManagerFactory` to the `EntityManager` and the best way to use this with my tested `Entities`.

From what I have read I need a `Service` layer and a `ServiceImpl` layer. My question is more of a configuration issue. Currently i have a project `com.myapp.entities`. I am considering creating a project `com.myapp.service` and `com.myapp.serviceimpl`. If I understood correctly the instatiation of the `EnitityManagerFactory` and `EntityManager` should go in `com.myapp.serviceimpl` but how do I inject these to work with my entities and what is the best way to create the `EntityManager`?

Also, which project does my `persistence.xml` go in?

Comment: I have expanded my question here in another question. The link is here for anyone interested in following. [Using @PersistenceContext and EntityManager for several schemas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843650/using-persistencecontext-and-entitymanager-for-several-schemas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Currently i have a project `com.myapp.entities`. I am considering creating a project `com.myapp.service` and `com.myapp.serviceimpl`*

I don't think you want to create different *projects* but different *packages* in the same project instead.

Entities, service and service implementation makes sense as long as they are cohesively designed. So if you split them into several projects then maintain your code will be very difficult and even deploy your applications based in this JPA persistence module will be also very hard because you'll have several dependencies. Not to mention maintainability once your applications are running in a production environment.

Also bear in mind JPA (persistence, actually) is the bottom layer in your application design. If you want to create applications with different capabilities but based on the same persistence background, then those capabilities should be located on top business-logic layers, not persistence layer.

> *Also, which project does my `persistence.xml` go in?*

As I've said you should actually have one project instead of several ones. But as general rule, `persistence.xml` should be present in the same project where your entities are.

> *I am trying to understand how to connect my `EntityManagerFactory` to
>   the `EntityManager` and the best way to use this with my tested
>   Entities.*

Since you say you are working on a Java SE application, then you have to take care of the lifecycle of both `EntityManagerFactory` and `EntityManager`;

While your `Service` could look like this:

```
public interface Service {

    public EntityManager getEntityManager();

}
```

The implementation might look like this:

```
public class ServiceImp implements Service {

    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager em;

    public Service() {
        super();
        emf = Peristence.createEntityManagerFactory("YourPU");
    }

    @Override
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        if (em == null || !em.isOpen()) {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
        }
        return em;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for all your answers! One other question. I do need to create different projects anyway for different db schemas and different functionality. The idea is to be able to offer some of the functionality in 1 application and all of it in another. The being said, I would have an entity manager for each schema correct?

I also saw some examples using `@PersistenceContext`. Is this necessary or optional?

Comment: You need a Persistence Unit for each schema, actually. You may have several entity managers for the same persistence unit, all of them asocciated with the same schema. On the other hand [`@PersistenceContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) annotation is inteded to be used with container-managed persistence, and is part of JEE standard. Is it necessary? No, but highly recommended, especially if you need to work with several persistence units. The the container will manage the whole entity manager's life-cycle for you.

Comment: This is a really broad topic and you have lot of frameworks/tools to work with. If you can define your needs more precisely in a different question, then I (and lot of other developers for sure) will be glad to lead you in the right way. @L.Young

Comment: Thanks @dic19 I have created a new question about my project [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843650/using-persistencecontext-and-entitymanager-for-several-schemas)

Comment: You are welcome :) @L.Young I've took a look to that question too. Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry I have a couple more questions. Does it make sense to make the `getEntityManager()` method to avoid conflicting access to an object? Also if they are in the same package, why would you need a `Service` and `ServiceImpl`?

Comment: No problem @L.Young 1) Not sure what do you mean *conflicting access to an object*. It makes sense due to OO paradigm: internal state should be always accessed/modified through getters/setters. Also please note that by doing just a few changes you can make `ServiceImp` implement Singleton pattern. 2) You need both as long as you are providing a *service*. The interface is a contract that could have several implementations. So if you are making use of a service you should't care about the concrete implementation.

Comment: 1) _Not sure what do you mean conflicting access to an object_ I mean to make sure I don't have multiple EntityManagers making changes to the same object and resulting in conflicting data.

2) _The interface is a contract that could have several implementations_ I decided that the FactoryDesignPattern is best for me. This would it make sense for the factory to access the methods through the interface so as not to expose the implementation of the `serviceImpl`? If not I don't see how having an interface is beneficial.

Comment: 1) Well there's nothing wrong on having several EntityManagers. An entity must be attached to an entity manager so it can be actually *managed*. So let's say you have an `Employee` instance selected and managed by EntityManager A and want to merge this entity using EntityManager B, then you'll have problems because this entity is attached to A not B. But avoiding this situation is something you have to take care of in your code. @L.Young

Comment: 2) Your choice makes sense to me. For example consider `EntityManagerFactory`. It is a factory of `EntityManager` objects. But `EntityManager` is actually an interface. You don't know and you actually don't care about the concrete implementation. You know it meets a contract and that's all you need to know. @L.Young

Answer (score 0):

Persistence.xml should be placed in resources/META-INF.
Then you just invoke entity manager in your serviceImpl this way:

```
public class ServiceImpl {

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("YOUR_PU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    public void save(Entity ent) {
       em.persist(ent);
    } 
}
```

Where "YOUR_PU" is your persistence-unit name.