# Using @PersistenceContext and EntityManager for several schemas

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I am currently working on a JavaSE project that I would like to build in the most effective way. My project is an employeeManagementSystem which has several schemas. For example I have one schema called `employees` which contains employee data and another schema called `company` which contains the company data.

Currently I have implemented my entities and tested these using `hibernate.cfg.xml` to make sure they are implemented correctly. For example, one such entity in the employee schema is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employees", uniqueConstraints= {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="idEmployees"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="idCardNumber"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="niNumber")
})
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private int idEmployees;


    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, updatable=false)
    @Size(min=1, max=15)
    private String idCardNumber;


    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, updatable=false)
    @Size(min=1, max=15)
    private String  niNumber;

    @Column(nullable=false, updatable=false)
    @Size(min=1, max=20)
    private String name;


    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Size(min=1, max=20)
    private String surname;

    // Other class variables

    //Constructors

    //getters & setters
}
```

I an now trying to use an `EntityManager` to manage my schemas. My persistence.xml for the employee schema is

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
             <persistence-unit name="EmployeesDAO" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
                <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
                <class>com.shopmanagementsystem.employeesdao.entities.Employee</class>
                //Other classes in this schema
                <properties>
                    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
                    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
                    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
                    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
                    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees"/>
                </properties>
             </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I want to create a Service and ServiceImpl class to manage the processes related to the entities.

Q1) Should I have a Service and ServiceImpl for each entity?

Some of my questions were answered already in a previous post [JPA EntityManager Construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811257/jpa-entitymanager-construction/25812588#25812588)

Q2) I further asked about using `@PersistenceContext` and was kindly advised to ask another question with a more detailed description of my project.

I am happy to add more details if I've left anything out and thank you for your advice and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Q1) Should I have a `Service` and `ServiceImpl` for each entity?*

Not necessarily. Based on the name of the persistence unit: `EmployeesDAO`, I'm assuming that `Service` and `ServiceImp` are intended to implement [DAO pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object), right? In this context you have to offer a contract (INSERT / UPDATE/ DELETE / QUERY) just for those entities that actually require it. For example you can have a table called `Category` which has a relationship with `Employee` like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="categories")
public class Category implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Id private BigInteger idCategory;
    @Basic private String description;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idcategory", referencedColumnName="idcategory")
    private Category category;
    ...
}
```

In this example you would have a `Service` to manage `Category` entities only if you need to. If those entities are managed by another application then you just need to have read privileges on `categories` table so the entity manager can map this data and that's it.

> *Q2) I further asked about using @PersistenceContext and was kindly advised to ask another question with a more detailed description of my
>   project.*

First of all please beware that [@PersistenceContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) annotation is intended to be used with container-based persistence, as part of a [Java EE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) application. You cannot use this annotation in plain Java SE platform.

On the other hand it doesn't mean you can't use JPA. Yes, it's perfectly possible, but you have to take care of the whole entity managers life-cycle. It is a common practice in this case to implement design patterns (such as [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) or [Factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) or [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)) in order to instantiate/access your entity managers *manually*.

In addition if you want to develop the top level layers of your application using Java SE and use container-managed persistence, then you can code the persistence layer using JPA and [Enterprise JavaBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans) architecture. This approach is not simple but has several advantages:

- You can offer the persistence layer as a *service* through EJB modules.
- Database connections and pools can be managed by the EJB container. This is extremely useful to separate database connection info from `persistence.xml` file.
- As already mentioned, the EJB container will manage the whole entity manager life-cycle.
- You can go further and leave container use [Java Transaction API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API) so you can forget (more or less) about transactional stuff.

---

#### Other comments

I know that posted `persistence.xml` is probably just an example but I have to mention that connect to the database as `root` user is not a good practice at all. Due to security reasons you should have several users with the right privileges to access your database, and likely none of them will ever need super-user privileges.

Finally, applications design is a really broad topic and it can be simple or complex based on your requirements. In addition there are several frameworks/technologies that can be used and is very very easy to get lost if you don't have any experience. My suggestion if you never did something like this before is to start with a very basic application and then go further.

Comment: thank you for your explanation @dic19 I am now reading up on EJBs and the design Patterns you mentioned to see which would best apply for me. Could you kindly clarify what you mean by "You can offer the persistence layer as a service through EJB modules."

Also in reply to your comment "connect to the database as root user is not a good practice at all." you are right it is only for testing purposes :)

Comment: You are welcome @L.Young 1) Sure. You can think EJB modules like stand-alone apps running in a container. Each session bean in a module must implement a `@Local` or `@Remote` interface (or both of them) to offer a contract to anybody interested in interact with it. You can make another *client* app that calls bean's methods remotely. In this sense it's pretty much like a server-client architecture: the EJB container would be the server and an EJB module would be the service. 2) I thought so :)

Comment: just to say thanks again because I've managed to run a successful test using `EntityManager` and the factory design pattern :D